# Get values repeated over 2 minute period in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have an events table, i need to get whenever an **overspeed** alarm has gone for over 2 minutes for any `deviceid` and flag them with `"emailSent"=1`.

What i'm doing is, grab all the events per vehicle like so `SELECT * FROM tc_events tm where "emailSent" = 0 and date(servertime) = date(now());` and then 1 by 1 comparing to its last known value like so

```
SELECT * 
FROM tc_events tm 
where deviceid = ? 
and id not in (?) 
and "attributes" = '{"alarm":"overspeed"}' 
and servertime > NOW() - INTERVAL '2 minute' 
and date(servertime) = date(now())
limit 1;
```

Maybe you guys can help me to get it in one single query.

```
CREATE TABLE public.tc_events (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    "type" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    servertime timestamp NOT NULL,
    deviceid int4 NULL,
    positionid int4 NULL,
    geofenceid int4 NULL,
    "attributes" varchar(4000) NULL,
    maintenanceid int4 NULL,
    "emailSent" int4 NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT tc_events_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

```
id    |type |servertime         |deviceid|positionid|geofenceid|attributes           |maintenanceid|emailSent|
------|-----|-------------------|--------|----------|----------|---------------------|-------------|---------|
631014|alarm|2020-09-03 20:46:36|     962|   8162779|          |{"alarm":"overspeed"}|             |        0|
630980|alarm|2020-09-03 20:42:43|     962|   8162521|          |{"alarm":"overspeed"}|             |        0|
630971|alarm|2020-09-03 20:40:08|     962|   8162385|          |{"alarm":"overspeed"}|             |        0|
607651|alarm|2020-09-02 14:46:13|     557|   7871167|          |{"alarm":"overspeed"}|             |        1|
607616|alarm|2020-09-02 14:44:33|     557|   7870620|          |{"alarm":"overspeed"}|             |        1|
591124|alarm|2020-09-01 17:13:05|     239|   7652421|          |{"alarm":"overspeed"}|             |        0|
590225|alarm|2020-09-01 16:30:31|     148|   7642031|          |{"alarm":"overspeed"}|             |        0|
590172|alarm|2020-09-01 16:28:35|     148|   7641467|          |{"alarm":"overspeed"}|             |        0|
588176|alarm|2020-09-01 15:14:42|     148|   7619691|          |{"alarm":"overspeed"}|             |        0|
582210|alarm|2020-09-01 11:34:11|     725|   7543204|          |{"alarm":"overspeed"}|             |        0|
```

Comment: Missing: Postgres version, actual table definition showing data types and constraints (`CREATE TABLE` statement).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, postgres version is (PostgreSQL) 12.2 and the post is now edited with the table creation query

Comment: The criteria which rows to inspect and how to filter *exactly* are also not clear to me. Seems like you only look at rows where `servertime > NOW() - INTERVAL '2 minute'`? What constitutes an "ongoing" overspeed alarm *exactly*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the mere *existence* of another overspeed alarm within the past two minutes constitutes "ongoing", `EXISTS` can do the job:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   tc_events tm
WHERE  deviceid = ? 
AND    id not in (?) 
AND    attributes = '{"alarm":"overspeed"}' 
AND    servertime > NOW() - INTERVAL '2 minute' -- only look at very recent rows?
AND    date(servertime) = date(now())  -- why? local midnight cancels "ongoing"?
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM tc_events
   WHERE  deviceid = tm.deviceid
   -- AND    id not in (?)  -- exclude here, too?
   AND    id <> tm.id  -- exclude self
   AND    attributes = '{"alarm":"overspeed"}' 
   AND    servertime <= tm.servertime -- same time possible?
   AND    servertime >= tm.servertime - interval '2 minute' 
   );
```

This reports "ongoing" events repeatedly for every new row.

Aside, your `attributes` column looks like a JSON document, and `varchar(4000)` is probably not the best way to store it ...